# How to make a proper 404 page?

Tags: http, web-applications, http-status-code-404

I am about to get rid of a few templates on one of my sites.  There are many pages under those templates like

```
city.php?city_id=1
city.php?city_id=2
city.php?city_id=3
...
```

What is the right way to tell Google that this page does not exist anymore so that it takes that page out of its index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want Google to delete the pages without carrying forward the references then a simple [HTTP 404](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=64033) will do the trick. If you want Google to forward the references (such as page rank and etc) to the new page then you would be better off using an [HTTP 301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Also See: [Google 301 Recommendation](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633).

Answer (score 1):

So you create 2 files:

- 1st file: a 404 page. Design it however you want.
- 2nd file: **MUST** be named `.htaccess`. Then put the following line of code in the `.htaccess` file.  Assuming your 404 page name is `404.html` you would write the following line of code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```